# SSH session_id in RFC 4253 (key exchange)

Tags: ssh, key-exchange

in RFC 4253 "SSH Transport Layer Protocol", [section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.2) specifies how session encryption and integrity keys (and IVs) are derived from the shared secret (K) and the exchange hash value (H). It uses, a part from these values and constants, a session_id. E.g.

```
Initial IV server to client: HASH(K || H || "B" || session_id)
```

I am confused since I though that H was actually the session identifier. What is session_id and how is it obtained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the [source code of openssh](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/kex.c#L877) as described in the RFC and we can simply trace its source from there:

```
/* K1 = HASH(K || H || "A" || session_id) */
if ((hashctx = ssh_digest_start(kex->hash_alg)) == NULL ||
    ssh_digest_update_buffer(hashctx, shared_secret) != 0 ||
    ssh_digest_update(hashctx, hash, hashlen) != 0 ||
    ssh_digest_update(hashctx, &c, 1) != 0 ||
    ssh_digest_update(hashctx, kex->session_id,
    kex->session_id_len) != 0 ||
    ssh_digest_final(hashctx, digest, mdsz) != 0) {
    [...]
```

From the RFC:

> The exchange hash H from the first key exchange is additionally used as the session identifier, which is a unique identifier for this connection.

This means, that the `session_id` is equal to `hash` (`H`) for the first key exchange. If there is another key exchange later, it is always the hash from the first key exchange.

Checking also [code of DH](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/kexdhc.c#L183):

```
/* calc and verify H */
hashlen = sizeof(hash);
if ((r = kex_dh_hash(
[...]

if (kex->session_id == NULL) {
    [...]
    memcpy(kex->session_id, hash, kex->session_id_len);
}

if ((r = kex_derive_keys_bn(ssh, hash, hashlen, shared_secret)) == 0)
    [...]
```

confirms this idea. First we calculate `H`, then we update `session_id` (if not set already) and then we derive the keys (code above).